# How to use a Data Segmentation filter inside CONCATENATEX()

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-platform

I am working on a Power BI report that has two tables. One of the tables has a One to Many relationship with the other, and I'm using the function CONCATENATEX() to concatenate the values of the table and put them in a column on the other table. I have a Data Segmentation visual that is supposed to filter the values before they enter the CONCATENATEX(), but it's not working as I expected. The function for the column is:

```
Attention Dates =
CONCATENATEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Tasks, [cr8a4_ticket] = Tasks[GUIDTicket] ),
        Tasks[DateTask]
    ),
    " - " & DAY ( Tasks[DateTask] ) & "/"
        & MONTH ( Tasks[DateTask] ) & "/"
        & YEAR ( Tasks[DateTask] ),
    "
    "
)
```

The function is supposed to extract the tasks related to the ticket and concatenate the dates, giving me a list like:

- 11/08/2023
- 12/08/2023
- 13/08/2023

The Data Segmentation visual is supposed to filter the dates, however it's not filtering the dates, it's passing all the dates, not filtering nothing.

Comment: `it's not doing it` a vague description of program behavior ... please describe what actually happens

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this way of using a predicate instead, where the ticket value is assigned to a variable and is not evaluated within `SUMMARIZE`:

```
Attention Dates =
VAR _ticket =  [cr8a4_ticket]
RETURN
CONCATENATEX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( Tasks, Tasks[GUIDTicket] = _ticket ),
        Tasks[DateTask]
    ),
    " - " & DAY ( Tasks[DateTask] ) & "/"
        & MONTH ( Tasks[DateTask] ) & "/"
        & YEAR ( Tasks[DateTask] ),
    UNICHAR(10) -- This is a line break character
)
```

Since you have not given any sample data, I haven't tested it.